# Index 16 beyond bounds [0 .. 15] - error

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing

I have a tableview which is either populated by one array or another array depending on if a UISwitch is on or off. When my switch is on, everything works fine, but when i turn it off it crashes when i scroll down to section 16. Everything works fine, and if i change the number of sections in table view to 15, it works without crashing. Though, now i miss the last section. I suspect that it might be the .plist file that i gather the information to the tableview don't match what i tell the tableview. Is this a common problem? If you need code i can give post it later.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Show the table view delegate / datasource methods and what you do when the switch is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero-based, so index 16 refers to the 17th item in an array. From the error in your title, your array has only 16 items (since the available indices are 0..15). So, trying to access the item at index 16 is an error.

It sounds like you're reporting more sections (or rows) than the number of items in your array. Ideally, you should determine the number of sections (or rows) from the array. That is, don't hard-code the number, just use the array's `-count` method.